# how to do sum with multiple joins in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that my question would be duplicated but I really don't know how to created sql which return results of sum with multiple join.

Tables I have

result_summary

```
num_bin id_summary count_bin
   3        172       0
   4        172       0
   5        172       0
   6        172       0
   7        172       0
   8        172       0
   1        174       1
   2        174       0
   3        174       0
   4        174       0
   5        174       0
   6        174       0
   7        174       0
   8        174       0
   1        175       0
```

summary_assembly

```
num_lot id_machine sabun  date_work   date_write id_product shift count_total count_fail count_good id_summary id_operation
 adfe      1       21312  2020-11-25  2020-11-25    1        A        10        2             8          170        2000
 adfe      1       21312  2020-11-25  2020-11-25    1        A      1000        1           999          171        2000
 adfe      1       21312  2020-11-25  2020-11-25    2        A       100        1            99          172        2000
 333       1       21312  2020-12-06  2020-12-06    1        A        10        2             8          500        2000
 333       1       21312  2020-11-26  2020-11-26    1        A     10000        1          9999          174        2000
 333       1       21312  2020-11-26. 2020-11-26    1        A       100        0           100          175        2000
 333       1       21312  2020-12-06  2020-12-06    1        A        10        2             8          503        2000
 333       1       21312  2020-12-07  2020-12-07    1        A        10        2             8          651        2000
 333       1       21312  2020-12-02  2020-12-02    1        A        10        2             8          178        2000
```

employees

```
sabun   name_emp
3532    Kim
12345   JS
4444    Gilsoo
21312   Wayn Hahn
123     Lee too
333     JD
```

info_product

```
id_product  name_product   
     1         typeA
     2         typeB
```

machine

```
id_machine   id_operation    name_machine
  1              2000           name1
  2              2000           name2
  3              2000           name3
  4              3000           name1
  5              3000           name2
  6              3000           name3
  7              4000           name1
  8              4000           name2
```

query

```
select S.id_summary, I.name_product, M.name_machine, 
E.name_emp, S.sabun, S.date_work, 
S.shift, S.num_lot, S.count_total, 
S.count_good, S.count_fail, 
sum(case num_bin when '1' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin1, 
sum(case num_bin when '2' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin2, 
sum(case num_bin when '3' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin3, 
sum(case num_bin when '4' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin4, 
sum(case num_bin when '5' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin5, 
sum(case num_bin when '6' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin6, 
sum(case num_bin when '7' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin7, 
sum(case num_bin when '8' then count_bin else 0 end) as bin8 
from result_assembly as R
join summary_assembly as S on R.id_summary = S.id_summary 
join employees as E on S.sabun = E.sabun 
join info_product as I on S.id_product = I.id_product 
join machine as M on S.id_machine = M.id_machine 
where I.id_product = '1' 
and E.sabun='21312' 
and S.shift = 'A' 
and S.date_work between '2020-11-10' and '2020-12-20' 
group by S.id_summary, E.name_emp, S.num_lot,
I.name_product,M.name_machine
order by S.id_summary;
```

result

```
id_summary name_product name_machine name_emp sabun date_work shift num_lot count_total count_good count_fail bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4 bin5 bin6 bin7 bin8
170           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-11-25  A   adfe        10           8          2      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
171           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-11-25  A   adfe      1000         999          1      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
174           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-11-26  A   333      10000        9999          1      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
175           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-11-26  A   333        100         100          0      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
178           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-12-02  A   333         10           8          2      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
179           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-12-02  A   333         10           8          2      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
180           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-12-02  A   333         10           8          2      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
181           TypeA        name1        Kim   21312 2020-12-02  A   333         10           8          2      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
182           TypeA        name2        Kim   21312 2020-12-02  A   333         10           8          2      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
186           TypeA        name2        Kim   21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      1    1    0    0    0    0     0   0
193           TypeA        name2        Kim   21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
194           TypeA        name2        Kim   21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
195           TypeA        name2        Kim   21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
196           TypeA        name2        JS    21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
197           TypeA        name2        JS    21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
198           TypeA        name2        JS    21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
199           TypeA        name2        JS    21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
200           TypeA        name2        JS    21312 2020-12-06  A   333         10           8          2      0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0
```

expected output(when sum by num_lot)

```
 num_lot count_total count_good count_fail bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4 bin5 bin6 bin7 bin8
   adfe     323          300        23      22    1   0    0    0   0     0   0
   333     4312         4300        12      10    2   0    0    0   0     0   0
```

All of them were modified from original one because they were non-English, so there would be typo.

Here now I need to sum by num_lot, name_product or sabun.
id_summary is unique.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: @S-Man I edited my post having expected data on it.

Comment: Why not simply: `SELECT num_lot, sum(count_total), sum(count_good), ... FROM (your query) s GROUP BY num_lot`?

Comment: @S-Man what does "s" in the front of GROUP BY mean? please understand me. I am a beginner.

Comment: @S-Man It works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I posted this into an answer. So, you can accept AND upvote the answer to close this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected in the comments: It seems like you simple need a subquery which groups your table by the column `num_lot`

```
SELECT 
    num_lot, 
    SUM(count_total), 
    SUM(count_good)
    -- some more SUM()
FROM (
    --<your query>
) s 
GROUP BY num_lot
```

It was asked in the comments what the `s` stands for: A subquery needs an alias, an identifier. Because I didn't want to think about a better name, I just called the subselect `s`. It is the shortcut for `AS s`

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to use `crosstab()`  -- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html

Comment: It is a tricky function.  There are some good tutorials and examples out there.  I wouldn't expect to learn it strictly from the documentation.  I always have to fuss with it a little to get it right.  It will pivot the data and summarize by category.  The hard part is if you don't know what those categories are ahead of time.  Hopefully you know already though so you don't have to go down that route.

Comment: There was typo. I have tried crosstab but I couldn't get understood because I am a beginner and  have not knowledges enough to understand. I think it would be good to fuss with it to get it right.